GDBus error in syslog: The name net.reactivated.Fprint was not provided by any .service
I have been trying to get my fingerprint reader to work on Ubuntu 22.04 - I have tried a number of things however no luck so far.
I thought I had cleaned up my effort however the syslog shows:
May 31 13:46:55 Precision-7510 gnome-shell[2485]: JS ERROR: Failed to initialize fprintd service: Gio.DBusError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name net.reactivated.Fprint was not provided by any .service files#012asyncCallback@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:114:23

I think that the expected fprintd service from dbus ??
But I am half guessing
